# Automapper: Custom mapping for multiple source arrays to a single destination array

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a source dto object being mapped to a configuration object. My Source object (ConfigDto) has several arrays of various types:
'''

```
public class ConfigDto
{
    public DogDto[] Dogs { get; set; }
    public CatDto[] Cats { get; set; }
}

public class DogDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class CatDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

'''
The Config object has a single array of objects that implement an interface (IAnimal):

'''

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void MakeSound();
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void MakeSound()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Bark!");
    }
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void MakeSound()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Meow!");
    }
}


public class AnimalConfig
{
    public IAnimal[] Animals { get; set; }
}
```

'''
Is there a better way to map the DTO to the config object. I am using a custom type converter and spinning through the source arrays to create a single destination array, but it feels like there should be a way to map the CatDto to Cat and DogDto to dog.
Note: for various reasons, I am unable to alter the structures of the source and destination objects.

'''

```
public class AnimalConverter : ITypeConverter<ConfigDto, AnimalConfig>
{
    public AnimalConfig Convert(ConfigDto source, AnimalConfig destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<IAnimal> destAnimals = new List<IAnimal>();

        foreach (var catDto in source.Cats)
        {
            destAnimals.Add(new Cat() { Name = catDto.Name }); //I am manually converting Cat. Could this be done via Automapper? 
        }

        foreach (var dogDto in source.Dogs)
        {
            destAnimals.Add(new Dog() { Name = dogDto.Name });  //I am manually converting Dog. Could this be done via Automapper? 
        }

        return new AnimalConfig(){Animals = destAnimals.ToArray()};
    }
}
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your automapper *profile configuration* add the following

```
CreateMap<CatDto, Cat>();
CreateMap<DogDto, Dog>();
```

On the custom mapper

```
public class AnimalConverter : ITypeConverter<ConfigDto, AnimalConfig>
{
    public AnimalConfig Convert(ConfigDto source, AnimalConfig destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<IAnimal> destAnimals = new List<IAnimal>();
        
        //add cats
        destAnimals.AddRange(context.Mapper.Map<List<Cat>>(source.Cats));

        //add dogs
        destAnimals.AddRange(context.Mapper.Map<List<Dog>>(source.Dogs));

        return new AnimalConfig(){Animals = destAnimals.ToArray()};
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what I needed. I figured the context.Mapper had something to do with it, but i didnt know that I could pull from mappings that were previously created at this point. Thanks so much!